# Initialize with a parameter

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Here is my code, I want to know how put my for-loop limit (IE 8) has a parameter in my constructor, so I could build this view with a specific number of line? And then, how to initialize such view ?

Thank you!

```
Ext.define('Prototype.view.FoodPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.foodpanel',

config: {
    height: 455,
    id: 'FoodPanel',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            height: 47,
            id: 'rowTitle',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    id: 'column_title_source',
                    width: 100,
                    label: 'Source',
                    labelWidth: '100%',
                    readOnly: false
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    id: 'column_title_user',
                    width: 100,
                    label: 'User',
                    labelWidth: '100%',
                    readOnly: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    id: 'column_title_object',
                    width: 160,
                    label: 'Object',
                    labelWidth: '100%',
                    readOnly: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    disabled: false,
                    id: 'column_title_factor',
                    width: 100,
                    label: 'Factor',
                    labelWidth: '100%',
                    readOnly: true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},

initialize: function() {
    this.callParent();
    var rows=[];
    for(var i=0; i<8;i++)
    {
        var row = Ext.create(Prototype.view.RowModel);
        if(i===4)
        {
            row.getComponent('mybutton').hide();
        }
        console.log(row.down('#rowLabel')._label);
        rows.push(row);
    }
    this.add(rows);
}

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, constructors of Ext components are expected to take only one parameter, which is the config object. Doing otherwise would be bad practice.

However, you're free to add what you want in the config...

For example, add a `numberOfLines` option in the config definition. You can later access the value of the option through `this.numberOfLines` or the generated getter `this.getNumberOfLines()`:

```
Ext.define('Prototype.view.FoodPanel', {
    // ...

    ,config: {
        // ...
        /**
         * Here's how you document a config option.
         * 
         * @cfg {Integer} [numberOfLines=8]
         */
        ,numberOfLines: 8 // default value of 8
    }

    ,initialize: function() {
        this.callParent();

        var n = this.getNumberOfLines();

        for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }
});
```

Then you can pass the option in the config, as usual:

```
Ext.create('Prototype.view.FoodPanel', {
    numberOfLines: 20
    // any other option you like...
});
```

Comment: I'll be trying that tomorrow, seems logical to me, thanks alot!

Comment: How can i add things to config in sencha architect there is no ''config'' field.  would you know?

Comment: No, sorry, I've never used Architect... But there is almost certainly some way to edit your classes code directly. If there is no `config` property in the code of a class you're editing, you can add it yourself in the class definition. Just keep in mind you have to call `this.initConfig(config)` in the constructor (see doc for `Ext.Base.initConfig`), if you're not extending from an Ext class that already does it.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. in architect, you can't modify code that was auto generated since he will overide your change and regenerate over those each time you save/build... :(

Comment: In that case, can't you override the generated class? Like this: `Ext.define('My.Override', { override: 'My.GeneratedClass', config: {...} })`. Then, you just have to ensure this "override class" is loaded and your change will take precedence without being overwritten. I'm not sure how the `config` option will react with the override, though...

Comment: I'll look into that, but I have bypassed my probleme for now, yet this would be helpful to achieve.